# How to fix strange change of window positions when using non-native resolution with triple monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I have a 3x1 monitor setup where I use my middle monitor for gaming.

When I'm gaming on my primary monitor on a non-native resolution, the window positions on the right monitor will change pretty strangely. The window positions on my left screen will remain the same.

I read online that this is the default behavior of Windows.

I made some photographs which demonstrates my problem:

[image: Desktop (native resolution)]

[image: In-game (lower resolution)]

Comment: yea that is what it does, the windows shift around on the monitor that has a different resolution because of the game, so they do not fall off the screen and can't any longer be grabbed (close x and title bars and all) . they shift off to the right, pushing windows on the right monitor, sometimes shifting the other windows in that direction. The normal thing to do is run the game in the native, and when you can't do that you either close things that would get in the way, or shift them around. If you think in the lower res the desktop will be in, you can confine things to that lower res before

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this?
Otherwise the third monitor would be pretty useless :/

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Set the middle screen up as if it was on the furthest right.

Not really a good option as it will be very confusing to navigate.

**Option 2:**
Set the game/application to run in (borderless) windowed mode.

Probably not possible as most games that won't run at high resolutions probably won't have a windowed mode.

**Option 3:**
Use this program [Display Changer 2](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641)! This allows for your low resolution games to run without affecting your other monitors!

I cannot test the effectiveness or what settings you need as I do not currently have any programs that affect my resolution in this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have an example configuration for Display Changer 2? Whenever I edit the XML file and try to configure I get an error "bad configuration"